# Why does Drake add an extra dimension when GetSolution is called on 1D array

Tags: drake

```
a = prog.NewContinuousVariables(1, "a")

neg_a = -a
```

If you call `result.GetSolution(neg_a)` and `result.GetSolution(a)`, the latter has shape (1,) and the former has shape (1, 1). Why the discrepancy? I feel like these things should have the same shape. This can easily become a source of broadcasting errors later on.

Comment: Thanks for reporting this! A short answer is that `result.GetSolution(a)` and `result.GetSolution(neg_a)` triggers different function in C++. Here `a` is a vector of symbolic variable, while neg_a is a vector of symbolic expression. I will try to fix this such that they return the same size numpy arrays.